# How to setup TensorFlow?

Tags: ubuntu, tensorflow, installation

I tried to install TensorFlow in windows but it seems near to impossible now. So, I decided to dual-boot my system with Ubuntu. And did so. Now I find so many different ways to setup TensorFlow, I don't know which one works best for me. And also, how actually do them. All those tutorials I find online are years old and some of them seem that they doesn't work anymore.

Please someone help me out with simple installation steps.. I am very new to Linux systems. It would be a great help. Thank you. :)

System: Ubuntu - v 15.04 ; 64bit.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualenv installation has worked very well for me.

https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv-installation

Comment: Thank you for your response. But I am stuck here
"Create a Virtualenv environment in the directory ~/tensorflow"
What exactly to do here?

Comment: Run the command listed below :) virtualenv --system-site-packages ~/tensorflow

Comment: Oops. Sorry. I thought I had to replace something in place of "--system-site-packages"

Okay. Now what's bash and csh. I am sorry for being so -_-

Edit: I am using bash. Got it. What about next step? How to know CPU or GPU?